# Broadcast a 1D array using a 2D array

Tags: python, list, numpy, list-comprehension, numpy-slicing

I have a 1D array `array_data` with ~10**8 elements.

I have a second array `array_index` which specifies the **bound**ing indices used to slice `array_data` with.

Below is Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of `array_data` and `array_index`:

```
import numpy as np

#Create data
array_data = np.arange(100)

#Randomly create indices
array_index = np.sort(np.random.randint(100, size=(10,2)))

#For each randomly created index, slice the array
array_sliced = [array_data[index[0]:index[1]]) for index in array_index]

#Now data is sliced, perform operation on the sliced data. For example:
val = []
for slice in array_sliced:
    val.append(np.nanmean(slice))
```

**Question:** What is the best way to slice `array_data` with `array_index` along `axis=1` so I can perform another task on the sliced arrays (e.g. `min`, `max`, `mean`)?

My solution at the moment uses list comprehension and conversion back to a numpy array. This method seems clunky and slow:

```
>>> np.array([np.nanmean(array_data[index[0]:index[1]]) for index in array_index], dtype=np.float64)
```

**EDIT:** Added Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (works in python 2.7).

Comment: given I understand it correctly, won't this result in an array where a "row" can have a different number of columns?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: What's the length of `array_index`?

Comment: I've made an edit to my original question. With a minimal and complete example of what I am trying to achieve. My question was asking, if there a better way to perform this task (e.g. a faster method)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get a list of arrays of varying size:

```
In [63]: [len(x) for x in array_sliced]
Out[63]: [3, 46, 38, 9, 73, 66, 3, 23, 40, 36]
```

(you also get this from `np.diff(array_index,axis=1)`)

A general observation is that when dealing arrays of differing sizes, it is quite difficult to treat them in any sort of 2d manner.

You might be able to generate a (10,100) mask, True for values you want to keep in each row, False for the omits.  Or maybe `np.nan` for the omits.

Or think in terms of padding these 10 arrays so they fit in a (10,73) array, again with an appropriate padding element (0, nan, etc).

Comment: That sounds great. Would creating a mask from index values specified by `array_index` be slow, especially if padding is involved?

Comment: I can't  generalize speeds with a complex task like this.